# Hive creates empty table, even there're plenty of file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I put some files into hdfs (`/path/to/directory/`) which contain data like following;

```
63  EB44863EA74AA0C5D3ECF3D678A7DF59
62  FABBC9ED9719A5030B2F6A4591EDB180
59  6BF6D40AF15DE2D7E295EAFB9574BBF8
```

All of them named as `_user_hive_warehouse_file_name_000XYZ_A`. These files had downloaded from another hdfs.

I'm trying to create external table via Hive;

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE users(
id int,
user string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION '/path/to/directory/';
```

It says;

```
OK
Time taken: 0.098 seconds
```

`select * from users;` returns **empty**.

`select count(1) from users;` returns **0**.

Hive creates the table successfully, but it's always empty. If I put another file like another.txt, that contains the sample data mentioned above, `select count(1) from users;` returns **3**.

What am I missing, why the table is empty?

**Environment**:

- JDK 7
- Hadoop 2.6.0
- Hive 0.14.0
- Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are encountering an issue that is peripherally discussed in [HIVE-6431](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6431).  In particular, this comment is the important one:

> By default, FileInputFormat(which is the super class of various formats) in hadoop ignores file name starts with "_" or ".", and hard to walk around this in hive codebase.

The workaround is probably to avoid using filenames that begin with `_` or `.`

Answer (score 2):

When you run any command on Hive, it is run internally as a MapReduce Job on the HDFS path that you stored the file. The job uses the FileInputFormat to read the HDFS files which has a hiddenFileFilter which ignores any files starting with underscore ("_") and ("."). You can actually set other files to ignore by setting the [FileInputFormat.SetInputPathFilter](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#setInputPathFilter(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf,%20java.lang.Class)) to a CustomPathFilter. Hadoop uses the files with underscores are "special" files to show job output and logs. This is probably why they are ignored.