# getting empty table from hive using spark with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I want to write scala code using spark to fetch dataframe from hive server.I used following code-

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation
import scala.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val configuration = new Configuration
configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos")
Properties.setProp("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5LocationInMySystem)  
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration)   
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal,keytabLocation)

val spSession = SparkSession.builder().config("spark.master","local").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/project_name/spark-warehouse/").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
spSession.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url","jdbc:hive2://host:port/default;principal=hive/host@realm.com")
.option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
.option("dbtable", "tablename").load().show()
```

getting output like

```
column1|column2|column3....
```

(only this much output)

While running, Program waits for the first time saying:

```
Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri:(url)
Code generated in 159.970292 ms
```

then some lines...then again:

```
will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri:(url)
INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
```

and it gives empty table

i have searched-

[Spark SQL RDD loads in pyspark but not in spark-submit: "JDBCRDD: closed connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268657/spark-sql-rdd-loads-in-pyspark-but-not-in-spark-submit-jdbcrdd-closed-connect)

[Hive creates empty table, even there're plenty of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181085/hive-creates-empty-table-even-therere-plenty-of-file)

[Hive Table returning empty result set on all queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094261/hive-table-returning-empty-result-set-on-all-queries)

but either they don't explain what i want or i am unable to understand what they are telling.For second link, I tried but could not find how to use setInputPathFilter in scala

dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: did you try [enableHiveSupport](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) ?

Comment: @ Ramesh Maharjan After adding .enableHiveSupport() got error: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState'. Searched many stackoverflow links now it looks like val spSession =SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("appname").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",wareHouseLocation).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()  still getting error :  Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState'.

Comment: what did you give in wareHouseLocation?

Comment: when i didn't add anything then in the logs it was showing file:/Users/myusername/IdeaProjects/myprojectname/spark-warehouse/  so i just added this. this is a place on my system

Comment: did you do `.config("spark.sql.‌​warehouse.dir","/Users/myusername/IdeaProjects/myprojectname/spark-wareh‌​ouse")`?

Comment: Actually i used file:/Users/myusername/IdeaProjects/myprojectname/spark-ware‌​house/ but what you are telling also gives the same error

Comment: can you update the question with full error log?

Comment: question updated with full error log

Comment: can you also update the question with the versions for spark, scala and hive?

Comment: question updated with dependencies

Comment: can your change your spark-core and spark-hive versions to be same?

Comment: i tried upgrading version of spark-hive but then i get 'version not found' error. if i downgrade spark-core to 2.0.0 i have to add a lot of dependencies one after another. still getting error. can you list dependencies? Because, i am unable to find correct dependencies.

Comment: why do you have `.option("url","jdbc:hive2://host:port/default;
principal=hive/host@realm.com")` in separate lines?

Comment: again updated but status is same

Comment: what is realm.com? can you try `.option("url","jdbc:hive2://host:port/default;principal=hive/_HOST@realm.com")`?

Comment: do you mean just put a underscore before host? after trying that i get errors like SASL negotiation failure and GSS initiate failed